# How do I construct this matrix in an efficient way?

Tags: python, performance, matrix, vectorization

I have a matrix `A` with dimension `(T,k)`. I want to construct the following block matrix for positive integers `m` and `t1, t2 < T`:

[image]

Here, `Im` is the identity matrix of dimension `m` and `A[t,i]Im` is a diagonal matrix with all diagonal elements equal to `A[t,i]`. Is there an efficient way to write this, perhaps without any loops? Here is my current code (setting `t2 = t, t1 = 0`) but it is very inefficient

```
B = np.zeros([k*m,t*m]) 
for i in range(filter_count):
    for j in range(t): 
        B[i*m:(i+1)*m,j*m:(j+1)*m] = np.diag(np.repeat([A[t-j,i]],m))
```

Comment: Try a kronecker product of `fliplr(A)` with `I_m`  Check out the help on `numpy.kron`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Kronecker product of `fliplr(A)` with `eye(m)`, for example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
Im = np.eye(3)
R = np.kron(np.fliplr(A), Im)

print('A:\n', A)
print('Im:\n', Im)
print('R:\n', R)
```

which prints

```
A:
 [[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
Im:
 [[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
R:
 [[3. 0. 0. 2. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 3. 0. 0. 2. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 3. 0. 0. 2. 0. 0. 1.]
 [6. 0. 0. 5. 0. 0. 4. 0. 0.]
 [0. 6. 0. 0. 5. 0. 0. 4. 0.]
 [0. 0. 6. 0. 0. 5. 0. 0. 4.]]
```